# Why is “Rectangled” not accepted usage?

Tags: word-usage, orthography, diction

Why is “Rectangled” not accepted usage (MS Word (and MS Outlook) always consider it a mistake)?

For example, here is the usage in a sentence:

*Select the “CTF” entry (rectangled above), and then click the “OK” button that will become enabled.*

If I write “circled” instead of "rectangled," *that* is accepted.

So why is “rectangled” not accepted?

Here is an example of something (a tree) being circled and something else (a rock) being rectangled:

[image]

Comment: Because it sounds ugly.

Comment: It just doesn't square with idiomatic English.

Comment: It is a word.  It is accepted usage according to the OED, but it is not frequently used.  Word-checking software is not an authority on language, but rather a tool for assisting as much as a computer can.  Your sentence is fine.

Comment: Go ahead and use it. There's no law against it. MS Word doesn't dictate how you use the language. Nothing dictates how anyone uses the language, in fact, which is why questions asking "why" are essentially unanswerable.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rectangled

Comment: I know it isn't what you were asking, but if you are just annoyed by MS Word highlighting it for correction, you can right-click on it and select 'Add to dictionary' to add it to your local custom dictionary. Then it won't underline it in future.

Comment: I agree with The Photon (answer below) that "boxed" is a more common way to say "enclosed in a rectangular box"; I also think that this preference is likely to get stronger, not weaker, as people work with software such as Adobe Acrobat and Photoshop—where the rectangular area provided (by default) for entering a label, caption, or other text in a layout is called a "text box"—not  "text rectangle."

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it is not a question for linguists, but a bug report for Microsoft. As far as the English language is concerned, the word is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft is marking this word because it's so uncommon that a typical English reader might not understand it if you used it without a visual example on the same page.

The word (and this usage) is uncommon because the word "boxed" is much more commonly used to describe a region of an image enclosed in a rectangular line.

Why do we use "boxed" more often than "rectangled"? Maybe because "boxed" is shorter and easier to say, or maybe just because the evolution of a language is unpredictable.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rectangled

Comment: @Kris, even if it is a documented word, it's pretty uncommon: [Ngrams link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rectangled%2Cboxed&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Crectangled%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Brectangled%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BRectangled%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cboxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bboxed%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBoxed%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Also, it looks like much of the usage of *rectangled* is for the meaning "having a right angle" rather than "having a box drawn around it". For example, I see many usages where (in the 19th C) a right triangle is called a "rectangled triangle".

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP has not asked for an alternative. The question is only "why not" and no more.

Comment: Many words may have synonyms/alternatives but that would not make the original word incorrect or unacceptable.

Comment: @Kris, Microsoft is marking the word because it is so uncommon that a typical reader might not understand it if you used it without a visual example on the same page. Why is it uncommon? Because there is an alternative and most speakers seem to like that alternative better. Why do they like it better? That's not for me to say.

Comment: @Kris, anyway if you have a better answer, please post it and I will upvote.

Comment: The reason SpellCheck flags the word is not necessarily that it's incorrect but more to alert of a **possible unintended typo**. See MS documentation for more.

Comment: @Kris, nowhere in my answer did I say the word is incorrect.